# Save Listview item with multiple rows and columns to Mysql Database

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010

Private Sub btnSave_ClientOrderStatus_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave_ClientOrderStatus.Click
        mysqlconn = New MySqlConnection
        mysqlconn.ConnectionString = serverstring

```
       Try
        mysqlconn.Open()
        Dim query As String = "insert into isad.invoice_table(Invoice, Clientnumber, Firstname, Lastname, ProductID, Name, Price, Qty, Description, Total, DateCreated) values "
        command = New MySqlCommand(query, mysqlconn)
        For i = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1
            query &= "('" & txtInvoice_ClientOrderStatus.Text & "','" & txtClientNumber_ClientOrderStatus.Text.Replace("'", "\'") & "','" & txtFname_ClientOrderStatus.Text.Replace("'", "\'") & _
                "', '" & txtLname_ClientOrderStatus.Text.Replace("'", "\'") & "', @ProductID" & i.ToString & ", @Name" & i.ToString & ", @Price" & i.ToString & _
                ", @Quantity" & i.ToString & ", @Description" & i.ToString & ", '" & txtTotal_ClientOrderStatus.Text & "',now())"
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID" & i.ToString, ListView1.Items(i).Text)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name" & i.ToString, ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(1).Text)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price" & i.ToString, ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(2).Text)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity" & i.ToString, ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(3).Text)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description" & i.ToString, ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(4).Text)
            query &= ", "
        Next
        query = query.Substring(0, query.Length - 2)

        READER = command.ExecuteReader
        SBP2.Text = "Status : Client invoice has been created"
        MsgBox("Saving Client Order Succeed", vbInformation, "Done")
        mysqlconn.Close()
        autoincrement_ClientOrderStatus()
        cleartext_ClientOrderStatus()
        btnSave_ClientOrderStatus.Enabled = False
        btnAdd_ClientOrderStatus.Text = "Add Transaction"
        READER.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        mysqlconn.Close()
    Finally
        mysqlconn.Dispose()

    End Try
End Sub
```

[heres my project image, maybe it can help you genospos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SR7Qk.png)

[Here's the error when i click save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YscB.png)

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a single access to DB you need to write a code for looping all rows to compose the query string:

This should work for you

```
Dim query As String = "insert into isad.invoice_table(Invoice, Clientnumber, Firstname, Lastname, ProductID, Name, Price, Qty, Description, Total, DateCreated) values "
Command = New MySqlCommand(query, mysqlconn)
For i = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1
    query &= "('" & txtInvoice_ClientOrderStatus.Text & "','" & txtClientNumber_ClientOrderStatus.Text.Replace("'", "\'") & "','" & txtFname_ClientOrderStatus.Text.Replace("'", "\'") & _
        "', '" & txtLname_ClientOrderStatus.Text.Replace("'", "\'") & "', @ProductID" & i.ToString & ", @Name" & i.ToString & ", @Price" & i.ToString & _
        ", @Quantity" & i.ToString & ", @Description" & i.ToString & ", '" & txtTotal_ClientOrderStatus.Text & "',now())"
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID" & i.ToString, ListView1.Items(i).Text)
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name" & i.ToString, ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(1).Text)
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price" & i.ToString, ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(2).Text)
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity" & i.ToString, ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(3).Text)
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description" & i.ToString, ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(4).Text)
    query &= ", "
Next
query = query.Substring(0, query.Length - 2)
```

Comment: Hi sir Genospos, i tried to configure your codes and i tried copy all the text but there's an error---- " You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax  to use near '" at line 1 ".. i tried to fix this but same problem occur, is there anything wrong with the codes??

By the way thanks for the reply

Comment: @Icebergman_NewProgrammer It seems there are two "('" after "VALUES". Replace "...VALUES ('" with "... VALUES ".

Comment: Sir genespos. I already tried that but same problem occured. Can you please help me for this. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: @Icebergman_NewProgrammer I can't figure out what's wrong in your query. If you can copy the query resulted from code and inset it into your question (with an edit) I'll be able to understand something else. I'm wondering if there are single quotes into any textbox. If so you can try adding `.Replace("'", "\'")` after every `textboxname.text` . I'll edit my answer this way to make you better understand.